# Как сделать jsonb_set для несокльких полей json&

Tags: postgresql

Иногда нужно изменить более одного поля в столбце с данными jsonb. Не понимаю из доки, как именно изменять несколько полей json. Знаю только как изменить одно поле `update table set column=jsonb_set(column, '{target_field}', 'newValue') where id='some_id';`
Пробовал перечислять просто через запятую все jsonb_set для разных полей но это не рабтает. Как же сделать?

Comment: Кажется нашел ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Не нужно делать несколько jsonb_set. Нужно просто передать json содержищий новые данные и обновятся только те поля json которые в запросе пришли а не все.

```
update column set json_column=json_column || '{"field1":"new_value", "field2":"new_value"}' where id = 'some_id';
```

и так далее.